# Can nginx be configured so that net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID is not returned to the client?

Tags: nginx, certificate, ssl-certificate

I use angular for ui with nginx as webserver.
Since we use self-signed certificate, when I issue https request from ui, I get net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID.
Is there anywhere in config of nginx to just bypass this error and let me in?

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: This error is not 'returned to the client'. As part of an HTTPS (SSL/TLS) handshake the server provides its certificate (usually with chain, but for selfsigned there is no chain) and the _client_ decides whether that cert can be trusted. Most clients, like browsers, do not trust a selfsigned cert you create, because anybody at all anywhere in the world can create one, and thereby steal and/or modify your valuable data that was supposed to be secure. Depending on your browser(s) and platform(s) you can usually configure it(them) to add your selfsigned cert as trustable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is very helpful and I now understand what I was not understanding :)